# Modeling strategies for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create the best modeling strategy for my application and am having a problem understanding the most efficient solution.

At the top layer we have Gamers. 
Gamers can have many Events. 
Events have many Participants (who are Gamers).

There can be any number of Participants in an Event, which is what is throwing me off. If they were a set number of Participants I could just have them as columns inside of the Events model with a foreign key to Gamers, but I'm not sure how to setup associations for this.

**My testing has them setup like so**

rails gen. model Gamer .. 
rails gen model Event .. 
rails gen model Participants .. event:references

**So now...**

Event has_many :participants  
Participants belongs_to :event

The problem I can't figure out is how to link Participants to their Gamer row?

I believe it is something similar the following, but the examples in the Rails guide don't fit my example exactly...

Gamer has_many :event_participants, :through => :events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this with some relation naming changes and a join table:

```
class Gamer
    has_many :hosted_events, :class_name => 'Event', :foreign_key => :host_id
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event
    belongs_to :host, :class_name => 'Gamer'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :gamers
end
```

And in your DB, you'll need the join table `events_gamers`, with `event_id` and `gamer_id` columns.  No model, though - Rails will take care of everything behind the scenes.

You really only need the two models.  Unless the relation "gamer G participated in event E" needs more data attached to it (say, "and brought chips!") - then it would warrant its own model (I'd call it Participation - Participant is a little misleading), and the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships would become `has many :through`s.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For your last example.. it would be Gamer has_many :participations, :through => :events correct? Not Gamer has_many :events, :through => :participations.. thanks!

Comment: It would be the second one:  A Gamer `has_many :events, :through => :participations`.  [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) are the docs, if you want even more details.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Single-Table-Inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815) and go about it like this :

1.Add a 'type' column to your participants table

2.Generate the Gamer model and make it inherit from the Participant model. (Inheritance)

3.Define the gamer's attributes in the participants table.

4.Setup your models like below:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :participants, :through => :registrations
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :events, :through => :registrations
end

class Gamer < Participant
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

So now you could do

```
gamer = Gamer.first #just an instance
gamer.events
event = Event.first #just an instance
all_participants = event.participants
gamers = event.gamers
```

Comment: Since the asker said participants are actually gamers, STI doesn't seem necessary.